# How to Implement the SQL Join Equivalent in MongoDB [ReactiveMongo]

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo

Given the following collections:

```
// Users
{ "_id": ObjectId("1"), "username": "user1", "role": "developer" }
{ "_id": ObjectId("2"), "username": "user2", "role": "projectManager" }
{ "_id": ObjectId("3"), "username": "user3", "role": "testManager" }
{ "_id": ObjectId("4"), "username": "user4", "role": "developer" }

// Projects
{ "_id": ObjectId("1"), "title": "Monitoring System", ... }
{ "_id": ObjectId("2"), "title": "Search Engine", ... }
{ "_id": ObjectId("3"), "title": "IDE for Scala", ... }

// Contributions
{ "_id": ObjectId("1"), "projectId": ObjectId("1"), "userId": ObjectId("1") }
{ "_id": ObjectId("2"), "projectId": ObjectId("1"), "userId": ObjectId("2") }
{ "_id": ObjectId("3"), "projectId": ObjectId("1"), "userId": ObjectId("3") }
{ "_id": ObjectId("4"), "projectId": ObjectId("2"), "userId": ObjectId("1") }
```

Using ReactiveMongo, how do I get all the users who contributed to project 1? I need the whole document... not just the user id.

Comment: I saw this answer... but it's not what I'm look for. I think there are better ways like the aggregation framework, but I was unable to find an example that matches my needs.

Comment: That's because it doesn't exist. :) MongoDB queries can only span a single collection.

Answer (score 0):

There are no joins in mongodb in this case I would embedd your data  and use true linking for example :

// Users

```
{_id : id, username: name, role: role, Contributions : [projectId1, projectId2, ..] }
```

That way you can do a simple find to get all user document that have a specific project id in the contributions array.

Embedding rich data into collections is what makes Mongodb so performant and flexible.

Comment: No... this doesn't work because in my real case a project could have hundreds of thousands of contributors...